# Put all values for each id in different column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table emp as

```
id|  doc |request_type
1 |  6   |  2
1 |  2   |  2
1 |  1   |  2
1 |  3   |  2
2 |  6   |  1
2 |  4   |  1
3 |  6   |  4
3 |  1   |  4
3 |  5   |  4
```

And I am trying to put all the `doc` values for each `id` in a new column.

Desired output

```
id|  doc     | request_id
1 |  6,2,1,3 |  2
2 |  6,4     |  1
3 |  6,1,5   |  4
```

Comment: Warning; this is a significant anti-pattern, and it ***will*** make future maintenence and development harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group_concat`

```
select id, group_concat(doc) as doc, request_id from <table> group by id,request_id
```

for more information read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

As @MatBailie mentioned, it is ok for selects, but you should not insert it into another column

Comment: Or even, the entry from the version the op is using? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat